# Setting default ssl backend in curl build

Tags: curl

How can I set the default ssl backend for curl when building it to Secure Transport (from macOS)?

I've tried the 2 following options in different builds, but both failed:

```
--with-default-ssl-backend='Secure Transport'
--with-default-ssl-backend=SecureTransport
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`curl` sources I found on Github](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/configure.ac), I think the string to configure Secure Transport as the default SSL backend would be `--with-default-ssl-backend=secure-transport`.